# React: Unhandled Rejection : Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have sign up page and when user press the button got some errors if there are any. But when inputs are correct and there is no errors, i got an another error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
```

Heres my code:

```
try {
            const response =  await signup(body);
            push('/login');
          } catch (error){
            if (error.response.data.validationErrors) {
                  setErrors(error.response.data.validationErrors);
                }
            
          }
```

Comment: which line has this error? is it on this line?  --> `if (error.response.data.validationErrors) {` ??

Comment: Use console.log(error) to check what is error, as it obviously does not have "response" object inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
    const response =  await signup(body);
    push('/login');
} catch (error){
    if (error?.response?.data?.validationErrors) {
        setErrors(error?.response?.data?.validationErrors);
    }
}
```

please try this as the condition does not getting data from the response so you can use the fallback

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no object called "data" in your response. Try to log your response and see whether there is an object called "data".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).